# Crying on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, mussar-ethics

Is it permissible to cry on Shabbos? What about if it is tears of joy? What are some halachos that pertain to crying (on Shabbos)? For example, can I tell someone something that may make them cry? What if I am sad, am I not allowed to cry? If I trip down stairs and I really hurt myself is it forbidden for me to cry? Sources please. Any answer will do but the more details the better.

Comment: See R' Daniel Travis' *Shabbos: Tasting Eternity* (section beginning [p. 192](http://books.google.com/books?id=zOzYI5TR_foC&pg=PA192#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

Comment: More directly, see Rama ([OC 288:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%97#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91)): וכן מי שיש לו עונג אם יבכה כדי שילך הצער מלבו מותר לבכות בשבת.

Comment: @Fred looks like an answer to me.

Comment: There's a story of the Gra who on Shabbat heard his sister died and didn't cry till just after Havdala.

Comment: This is a clear article with all the sources. http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/crying-on-shabbos/#ftn1

Answer (score 1):

#### The answer is yes.

As @Fred pointed in his comment, poskim addressed your question in SA OC 288, 2, I just want to show the Baer Heytev in name of the Taz:

> (ב) הצער מלבו:    וט"ז כתב דוקא מחמת רוב דבקות בהקב"ה מותר לבכות וכ"ה מצוי במתפללים בכוונה אבל כדי שיצא הצער מלבו לא ע"ש (ובאליהו רבה התיר).‏
>
> The Taz allowed to cry because of great attachment (to G-d), this phenomenon is current in persons who pray with concentration and feeling.  But to cry to purge emotional pain is prohibited.